# Get data from regex

Tags: php, regex

Is it possible to get numbers from this regex?

```
preg_match("/STEAM_\d:\d:\d*/", $SteamID, $matches)
```

I need to get all three digits to vars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You need capturing groups.

```
preg_match("/STEAM_(\d):(\d):(\d*)/", $inputStr, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

As you can see if you execute that, your digits will be in `$matches[1]`, `$matches[2]` and `$matches[3]`. If this pattern occurs multiple times in `$inputStr` use `preg_match_all` instead.